# Invalid Credentials - Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

The below api call always returns invalid credentials

```
$ch = curl_init();
$fileId = 'myfile_id';
$key = 'apikey';
$accessToken = 'access_token'

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/'.$fileId.'?key='.$key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken;
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Response

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }
```

I am calling the api immediatly after recieivng the access token. So I am sure that it is not expired and the api key is also correct.

Do anyone have any idea about this ?

Comment: You are manually entering the access token. Are you sure it's a valid access token? How did you acquire it?

Comment: @Martí I am taking the token from the file token.json, I am also confirming it is expired or not before taking

Comment: @Martí Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Where did you get this `token.json` from? Is it a service account key?

Comment: @Martí It will be autogenerated after user grant permission to access the drive

Comment: Oh so it's basically the saved access token. If you use [the API explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix=true), does it work? Ifso, if you use the generated curl code and change the values manually, does it work?

Comment: @Marti In the API explorer it is working fine, nothing else works

Comment: Try generating a new token. If you are using the code from the PHP Quickstart, you only need to delete the `token.json` and run the code again.